# Singular Fisher Information and nuisance parameters

Tags: fisher-information

I am interested in a problem where the Fisher Information matrix is singular and I want to treat some of the parameters as nuisance parameters.

If the FI matrix is singular, that means that some parameters or some linear combinations of them are indeterminable. So, one of the way to treat this problem is find the linear combinations of the parameters that correspond to the non zero eigenvalues and those respond to the zero eigenvalues and estimate only those that correspond to the non zero eigenvalues.

On the other hand, if you want to estimate some part of your parameter set, you can treat the rest as nuisance parameters and then invert the FI matrix and marginalise it and invert it again to obtain the FI matrix for the parameters of interest. But this won't work if the FI matrix is singular.

**So the question is:**

What happens if we know we can't estimate all the parameters (we are in the irregular model), but we want to see in this case what is my best estimate of a specific one, if we ignore all the others.

Could you refer me to some bibliography?

Comment: Are you referring to the Fisher Information *at the maximum likelihood estimate* or in general?  Note that in the former case it does not necessarily follow that the parameters cannot be estimated, whereas in the latter case attention should be focused on a submanifold of the parameter space--but not necessarily on linear combinations of parameters.

Comment: I mean in general and you are right, it doesn't need to be a linear transformation. But I also don't understand why in the first case it doesn't necessary mean that the parameters cannot be estimated. What would it mean? (It is a different question but it is interesting)